# how to make rules in model using yii framework?

Tags: yii

In my application I have 1 field name contact_no,in that i want validation like **+91-(999)-(846)-1062**

If I'm writing like this

> array('contact_no','pattern'=>'/^[0-9-()\s+]+$/'),

then i got error like

```
invalid validation rule. The rule must specify attributes to be validated and the validator name.
```

Then what to write in model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the syntax is not correct,try this:

```
array('contact_no', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[0-9-()\s+]+$/'),
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [CRegularExpression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CRegularExpressionValidator) with a 'pattern'. The validator name for this is 'match'.